# Display Terminal message on login

Tags: terminal, bash, launchd, plist

I want to display something like `### this is a test ###` when a new Terminal window is open (and ideally, in a way that can be disabled easily). On Linux this was straightforward; you'd create a script in `/etc/profile.d/` which would be responsible for `echo`-ing the message when a new Terminal session is opened.

I've been playing around with launchd to try to get this to work but to no avail. I've created an agent in `/Library/LaunchAgents/org.test.greeting.plist` with the following code (where the greeting.sh file is responsible for doing the `echo`) hoping to get some output when the user logs in.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>org.test.greeting</string>
    
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/test/greeting.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key><true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This hasn't worked, as the message is lost to the ether. However, I do know that the agent is running successfully. I know it is possible to redirect the output to a file using `StandardErrorPath` and `StandardOutPath` but those are not useful to me.

Does anyone know how to get this working with `launchd`, or maybe have another way of doing this?

Comment: Have you looked at the "message of the day"? - `man 5 motd`

Comment: "On Linux", of course, is a nonsense statement.  All your /etc/profile.d example means is that at least one Linux distribution has /etc/profile (for Bourne shells) set up to read a dot-d directory and execute what it finds there.  It wouldn't have anything to do with launchd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like the message of the day for this.  As tradition dictates...

```
me@Mac ~ % echo "Welcome to the University of East Westia" > /tmp/motd
me@Mac ~ % sudo mv /tmp/motd /etc
```

Note: /etc/motd is only displayed in a login shell, which is typical of Terminal.app on macOS.  If you typically run non-login shells, you should handle display of /etc/motd in your shell dot files.

Comment: Excellent, this works perfectly! And is very easy to undo when necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried editing your dotfiles?

As a reference, in my `~/.zshrc` I have at the very top the command `neofetch`. Per se, it is just a command you can execute from your shell. In this way, anytime I start a new iTerm2/Terminal window or tab I get the command executed and have this displayed.

[image: my terminal at launch]

The same can be done by writing at the top of your config file something as the following: `echo "### this is a test ###"`

Comment: This is not helpful, it is just an advertisement for homebrew and neofetch.

Comment: Sorry Marc, I just meant to make a practical example from my daily usage. Of course, I have no interest in promoting neither of those. I will try and edit the answer.

Comment: I love this! Checking out neofetch immediately. Thank you @MarcWilson for fixing my soft wording in my answer. I tested motd using Prompt app on iOS / iPadOS to ssh into a couple recent builds.